# Is measure theory important in set theory?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, set-theory, big-list

I'm looking for topics in measure theory that are related to set theory (descriptive set theory or otherwise). It seems that there's a lot of connection between topology and set theory and I'm wondering if the same is true for measure theory.

Edit: To be more specific, can one give some examples of areas where these subjects are related? For example, the only area I'm aware of is cardinal characteristics of the continuum where people study at which level, i.e. ordinal, additivity of certain measures on the reals fail.

Comment: Not really, I believe, but I'm not a set theorist.

Comment: I think it depends on the subtopics of set theory. What I can say for sure is that measure theory has a critical role in the early history of set theory (e.g., the discovery of measurable cardinal.)

Comment: Even though measures are not apparently important in most set theories, the idea that the collection of null sets form an ideal, and regarding sets in an ideal as *small* is seemingly prevalent in most subfields of set theory.

Comment: Look at volume 5 of Fremlin's monograph "Measure theory". https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mtcont.htm

Comment: (Though many descriptive-set-theoretic issues come up in topics in volume 3.)

Comment: Also, the theory of measure algebras and Maharam's theorem plays an important role in the study of forcing, particularly in relation to random extensions and real-valued measurability.

Comment: The question of what sets are Lebesgue measurable has been important to large cardinal theory. There are dep connections here with determinacy and its various definable versions.

Comment: The ergodic theory of group actions plays an important role in modern descriptive set theory.

Answer (score 3):

It is important. For example look at the work of [Alexander Kechris](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7Ekechris/) from Caltech. Also see the work of Furstenberg and Pestov.